# Get sales totals per account using model property in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Okay I thought I can google my way out of this but I am stuck.

Desired results are

```
 Account_name        Total
 local sales         1802.50
 int sales           0.00
```

from my models

```
class Account(models.Model):
    account_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    account_name   = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)


class Sales(models.Model):
    account_name = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='incomes')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    def sales_total(self):
        sales_total = Income.objects.values('account_name').order_by('account_name').annotate(sales_total=Sum('sales__total'))
        return sales_total
```

So in my template when I do

```
{% for account in accounts %}
    <tr>      
      <td>{{ account.sales_total }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I get

```
 Account_name     Total
 local sales      <QuerySet [{'account_name': 3, 'sales_total': Decimal('1802.5')}]>
 int sales        <QuerySet [{'account_name': 3, 'sales_total': Decimal('1802.5')}]>
```

Comment: try ```return sales_total.sales_total``` in models

Comment: I get the error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sales_total' when I apply the return statement

Comment: try in your **template** `{{ account.sales_total.sales_total }}`

Comment: @OmayerHasanMarif it gives empty in the tamplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to to this after so much research on the net

in the account model I defined a function to get the sales totals

```
def sales_total(self):
       return sum([item.sales_total() for item in self.incomes.all()])
```

The in the template got the values as `{{ account.sales_total }}`

Answer (score 0):

Change the sales_total func:

```
def sales_total(self):
        sales_total = Income.objects.values('account_name').order_by('account_name').annotate(sales_total=Sum('sales__total'))
        return sales_total[0].sales_total
```

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

Comment: changing the func on the return line i get the error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'sales_total'

Comment: Ok, you can try to use ````return sales_total[0][sales_total]```` then. But right approach is not to use .values(), but insted get the Queryset by usung .all():
````sales_total = Income.objects.all().order_by('account_name').annotate(sales_total=Sum('sales__total'))````